# bootstrap tabbar inside the sticky side-bar. .As mentioned in picture

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap tabbar inside the sidebar image

[image]

I want one sticky sidebar on left containing data on right side.

On click sidebar-tab data in right side should change.

on up/down left-sidebar should stick on the middle of the screen till the height of the right side of the body ends.

Also, i need one more tab-bar in right side of the body.

Here i have used js-code but on scroll-up inner bootstrap tab-bar also scrolled down with outer left-scrollbar.

Here is the code what i have used

```
//-----html 
<div class="tabbar"> <--used as outer sidebar--->
ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="sidebar">
      <li class="active"><a href="#a" data-toggle="tab">About Us</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#b" data-toggle="tab">Our Philosophy</a></li>
        .....
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content right-bar">
         <div class="tab-pane active" id="a">

         <--inner tabbar-->

         <h2>Inner tab</h2>
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
          </ul>

          <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
              <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
              <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
            </div>
          </div>

         </div>
         <div class="tab-pane" id="b">
         ....
         </div>

</div>
```

Tab-left keep scrolled in right pan

```
// $(function() {

//     var $sidebar   = $("#sidebar"),
//         $window    = $(window),
//         $footer    = $("#footer"), // use your footer ID here
//         offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
//         foffset    = $footer.offset(),
//         threshold  = foffset.top - $sidebar.height(); // may need to tweak
//         topPadding = 15;

//     $window.scroll(function() {
//         if ($window.scrollTop() > threshold) {
//             $sidebar.stop().animate({
//                 marginTop: threshold
//             });
//         } else if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
//             $sidebar.stop().animate({
//                 marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
//             });
//         } else {
//             $sidebar.stop().animate({
//                 marginTop: 0
//             });
//         }
//     });

// });
```

When i scrolled up inner body(tab-content)of inner tabbar also scrolled down see here is the image

Problem occurred on scrolled up

[image]

Comment: The title and the content of the question need to be more clearly

Comment: HI, @Kalamarico i have updated the question.please give me solution.

Comment: Hi @SERVO, hehe promise i will check when i have time, i didn't tell you for myself, i did tell you for anyone. Now, your question have more sense, I'm sure that soon you will have answers ;)